# Unable to share image & text using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using the following lines of code to share an image with a text.

```
let shareController: UIActivityViewController = {
        let activities: [Any] = [image!, message]
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activities, applicationActivities: nil)
        return controller}()
        screen.present(shareController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**image** is a `UIImage`.

**message** is a `String`.

I am able share the image if I only add the `image` to activities. But when i add message with image I am only able to share the message and the image doesn't show up.

I'm new to iOS app development so I may miss something very obvious. I tried searching for solutions but only found the same issue raised by other people without a solution. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.